# Big-O of code fragment with nested loops

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

We've received a fragment of code to find its big-O:

```
for(int i = 1;i ≤ n;i = 2 ∗ i)
    for(int j = 1;j ≤ i;j = 2 ∗ j)
        for(int k = 0; k ≤ j; k++)
             //do something elementary
```

The first line should be O(log(n)) but it gets complicated by the second line and even more so by the third. I initially thought that the second line could also be O(logn) but the upper limit j < i might dispute this.
Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated!